# Switch between button bars

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#000000" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/taoFooter">
        <com.example.gamedice.DrawingPanel
            android:id="@+id/taoCanvas"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="#000000" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/taoFooter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        style="@android:style/Holo.ButtonBar">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/roll1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/roll1"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless"
            android:onClick="rollTaoDice" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/roll2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/roll2" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless"
            android:onClick="rollTaoDice" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/roll3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/roll3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless"
            android:onClick="rollTaoDice" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/roll4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/roll4" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless"
            android:onClick="rollTaoDice" />
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In addition to other items in the layout, this layout has a button bar consisting of four buttons at the bottom of the screen. Based on user input, I want to be able to replace this button bar with another predefined set of buttons, and then be able to change back later.

Since I know what the alternate set of buttons will be ahead of time, I thought it might be possible to use an alternate layout xml file, but I couldn't figure out how to do that. Can anyone give me some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your second set of buttons in a layout like you did with the first, then in the layout xml file set the attribute `android:visibility="gone"` on the second layout. In your code you can call `setVisibility(View.GONE)` for one layout (e.g. `taoFooter`) and `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` on the other layout when you need to switch the buttons out.

Alternatively, if you easily want to add some animations you can add a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html) around your two alternate button layouts. Only the first one is visible by default. You can switch to the next layout with `showNext()`. Add calls to `setInAnimation()` and `setOutAnimation()` before that to enable the animations.